# Is it possible to get someone's code signing certificate revoked?

Tags: malware, certificate, adware, code-signing

I recently had to clean up someone's computer because they were tricked into installing a bunch of things without their knowledge. The horrible thing about it was that the installer was signed with a company name.

How would one go about reporting this "company" with the goal of having their certificate revoked?

Comment: Well, you could report to the issuer e.g. verisign. You could also find their web sites hosting provider and report the activity to them, in hopes that the host is supportive of your cause (not to revoke certificate but maybe to drop the hosting account). If its a us or Canadian company you could report to the BBB if you think they're committing fraud of some sort. Your mileage may vary on any of these.

Comment: Having a certificate doesn't mean that the certificate holder is endorsed by any entity; all it does is allow for signing to verify that the certificate holder generated said content.

Comment: Anyone can create a certificate and claim the owner is anyone.  Was the certificate self-signed by chance?

Comment: No. The certificate was issued by Comodo. But I can't find any Comodo contact information for my specific issue.

Comment: @ernie: Thanks but I do understand what they are - I have one with Thawte. The problem is that the average user will trust a software package that's signed with a CA and they're taking advantage of that to peddle their malware.

Comment: @Sosukodo My point is that the CA doesn't really have any control over how someone uses a cert.  I'm going to guess that the application the user used had some fine print or something that the user implicitly agreed to install the toolbars/malware/whatever, so they've covered their legal bases.  Yeah, the software was sketchy as hell, but the CA isn't a regulatory agency (nor would I guess any CA wants to enter the morass of judging who's "worthy" of having a cert)

Comment: I fear that you're correct. Ive written a few CAs and asked how to get started signing my viruses and trojans with their certificates. Their responses should be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

No You can not revoke but you can complain to concern authority from where the Code Signing certificate is been issued to user.

The Certificate authority will take appropriate action towards the user.